# angular material position of dialog with respect to opening element

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material2

I am using angular material https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview and my dialog works as expected. The only trouble is that it opens in the middle of the page as default position. My requirement is to be able to open it next to the link i am clicking.

the current code of the table in which there is icon to show this dialog is as follow:

html

```
<table>
 <tr *ngFor="let opty of optys" class="fa-table-data-row">
                    <td class="fa-table-data-col fa-text-link" (click)="createTab(opty.name)">{{opty.name}}</td>
                    <td class="fa-table-data-col">{{opty.account}}</td>
                    <td class="fa-table-data-col">{{opty.winPct}}&nbsp;
                          <mat-icon class="fa-icon"  *ngIf="highGap(opty.winPct, opty.aiWinPct) == true" (click)="openWinPctDialog(opty.name, opty.winPct, opty.aiWinPct)">warning</mat-icon></td>
                     <td class="fa-table-data-col" *ngIf="opty.recommendedAction != undefined">{{opty.recommendedAction[0].title}}</td>
</tr><table>
```

.ts

```
 openWinPctDialog(optyName:string, winPct:string, aiWinPct:string){
    this.winPctDialog.open(WinPctComponent,
                            {  width: "300px",
                               data: { name: optyName, winPct: winPct,  aiWinPct: aiWinPct}
                            })
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried Menu? https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview

Comment: menu does not sound like the right component for dialog.

Comment: may be overlay? you can check my article at https://medium.com/@juliapassynkova/material-cdk-overlay-with-rxjs-e6e4a7923229

Answer (score 0):

The below use of clientX and clientY to set the co-ordinates should help.

```
openEditDialog(evt: MouseEvent) {
const target = new ElementRef(evt.currentTarget);
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ContentWindow, {
        position: {left:  **evt.clientX +'px'**  , top: **evt.clientY +'px'** }
  });
```